# how to enable auto scaling property in chart control using c#

Tags: c#, charts

> In my application im having a chart control that is working fine. For every 1 second updating the x-Axis values and y-axis values in the chart. I want to enable auto scaling for the chart control programmatically for y axis. Please refer my code below,

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

series1.Name = "Series1";
series1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series1.MarkerColor = Color.BlueViolet;
series1.MarkerSize = 10;
series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;            
series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
series1.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
```

> How to enable auto scaling programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

        series1.Name = "Series1";
        series1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        series1.MarkerColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        series1.MarkerSize = 10;
        series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        //series1.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
        //series1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
        series1.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
```

> Working fine

Answer (score 1):

`chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN;`

But some people have trouble with the above one,
so try this if that doesn't work

`chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();`